# Random access performance in HBase & block size in HDFS

Tags: hbase, hdfs

HBase can use HDFS as back-end distributed file system. However, their default block size is quite different. HBase adopts 64KB as default block size, while HDFS adopts at least 64MB as default block size, which is at least 1000 times larger than HBase's.

I understand that HBase is designed for random access, so lower block size is helpful. But when accessing a 64K block in HBase, is it still necessary to access one 64MB block in HDFS? If it is true, can HBase handle extremely random access well?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Blocks are used for different things in HDFS and HBase.  Blocks in HDFS are the unit of storage on disk.  Blocks in HBase are a unit of storage for memory.  There are many HBase blocks that fit into a single HBase file.  HBase is designed to maximize efficiency from the HDFS file system, and they fully use the block size there.  Some people have even tuned their HDFS to have 20GB block sizes to make HBase more efficient.

One place to read more to understand what is going on behind the scenes in HBase is: http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#regionserver.arch

If you have perfectly random access on a table that is much larger than memory, then the HBase cache will not help you.  However, since HBase is intelligent in how it stores and retrieves data, it does not need to read an entire file block from HDFS to get at the data needed for a request.  Data is indexed by key, and it is efficient to retrieve.  Additionally, if you have designed your keys well to distribute data across your cluster, random reads will read equally from every server, so that the overall throughput is maximized.

Answer (score 8):

### HBase

HBase persists data into large files called HFiles, these are big in size (order of magnitude of hundreds of MB, or around GB).

When HBase wants to read, it first checks in the memstore if the data is in memory from a recent update or insertion, if that data is not in memory it will find the HFiles having a range of keys that could contain the data you want (only 1 file if you ran compactions).

An HFile contains many data blocks (the HBase blocks of 64kB by default), these blocks are small to allow for fast random access. And at the end of the file, there is an index referencing all these blocks (with the range of keys in the block and offset of the block in the file).

When first reading an HFile, the index is loaded and kept in memory for future accesses, then:

- HBase performs a binary search in the index (fast in memory) to locate the block that potentially contains the key you asked for
- Once the block is located, HBase can ask the filesystem to read this specific 64k block at this specific offset in the file, resulting in a single disk seek to load the data block you want to check.
- The loaded 64k HBase block will be searched for the key you asked, and the key-value returned if it exists

If you have small HBase blocks, you’ll have more efficient disk usage when performing random accesses, but it will increase the index size and the memory needs.

### HDFS

All the file system accesses are executed by HDFS which has blocks (64MB by default). In HDFS the blocks are used for distribution and data locality, which means that a file of 1GB will be splitted in 64MB chunks to be distributed and replicated. These blocks are big because to ensure that batch processing time is not only spent in disk seeks, as the data is contiguous in that chunk.

### Conclusion

HBase blocks and HDFS blocks are different things:

- HBase blocks are the unit of indexing (as well as caching and compression) in HBase and allow for fast random access
- HDFS blocks are the unit of the filesystem distribution and data locality

The tuning of the HDFS block size compared to your HBase parameters and your needs will have performance impacts, but this is a more subtle matter.